# How many connected "pixelclouds" can be drawn in a 10 x 10 grid?

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:**

How many unique pixel-shapes can be drawn in a 10 x 10 grid?

**Rules:**

1 The pixels have to be connected to each other on a corner or edge to form a shape.

2 Identical shapes are only counted once. Their position inside the grid is irrelevant.

3 (optional) There are no holes allowed to appear in the shape. (No white pixels surrounded by 4 or more corner / edge attached black pixels.)

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVHyu.png)

Comment: There's going to be a lot of those: colour the $50$ pixels in a chequered pattern, and then any of the $50$ remaining pixels can be coloured or not, giving you at least $\frac{2^{50}}{8}$ shapes ($8$ to account for possible rotations and reflexions). This is a very crude lower bound that can be improved significantly. If you cannot get the exact number, are you interested in estimates like that one?

Comment: I assumed the number is absurdly high, yes, but it would be interesting to know if it is somewhat displayable in the e+xx realm or near infinity. The exact number would be perfect.
Your checkered pattern approach reminded me of a third (optional) rule i forgot. There are no holes allowed to appear in a shape. I will edit this in the original post.
Also your method would only account for shapes which completely fill the grid – not for ones that are smaller. Or does it?

Comment: $2^{100}\approx 1.26765 \times 10^{30}$ counts all possible (black/white) colorings of the grid, and this is considerably more than the number you seek.